# Given a non-negative integer N, returns the number of non-negative integers similar to N in Python

Tags: python, numbers

Develop a function:

Two non-negative integers N and M are said to be similar if their decimal representations can be obtained from each other by rearranging their digits. Note that a correct decimal representation does not contain leading zeroes.

```
Class solution { public int solution(int N); }
```

that, given a non-negative integer N, returns the number of non-negative integers similar to N.

For example, given N =1213 the function should return 12 because there are twelve integers similar to 1213, namely: 1123, 1132, 1213, 1231, 1312, 1321, 2113, 2131, 2311, 3112, 3121, and 3211

Given N = 123 the function should return 6 because there are six integers similar to 123, namely: 123, 132, 213, 231, 312 and 321

Given N = 100, the function should return 1 because there is only one similar integer. 001 and 010 are both incorrect decimal representations of integers.

Given N = 0 the function should return 1 because there is only one similar integer (the number itself).

Currently, I have a function that creates all the permutations though I have more then 12 for N = 1213. I dunno how they exactly get this number.

```
def solution(N):
  
   res = [int(x) for x in str(N)] 
   result_perms = [[]]
   
   for n in res:
       new_perms = []
       for perm in result_perms:
         for i in range(len(perm)+1):
           new_perms.append(perm[:i] + [n] + perm[i:])
           result_perms = new_perms
   return result_perms
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is "more then 12 for N = 1213"? What are the specific integers that your solution is returning? What exactly does "similar" mean? (I can guess, but as far as I can tell this isn't a mathematical concept and you should be explicit.) Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` is useful for this type of problem. My solution:

```
import itertools
def solution(N):
    count = 0
    for i in set(itertools.permutations(str(N))): # we use set() to eliminate duplicates, and cast N to a string to make it iterable
        perm = "".join(i)
        if str(int(perm))==perm and int(perm) >= 0: #check to ensure that we have no 0's at the front of this permutation
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Or, `return sum(1 for e in {''.join(t) for t in permutations(str(n))} if str(int(e))==e)`

Comment: I'd definitely use this for my code! It's more concise, but harder to add comments to... We do need set() applied to the permutations so that we don't include 1123 twice (in Brandini's example), though.

Comment: The portion `{''.join(t) for t in permutations(str(n))}` IS a set. It is a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: Ah I see! My tired eyes didn't notice the braces were curly. Thanks!